# -nw or & in the terminal does not work anymore

Tags: macos, emacs, terminal, new-window

For instance, when using emacs I want to open the file in a new window so the file pops up, but in my terminal when I do emacs filename -nw (or &) it opens it inside the terminal. Any suggestions?

Comment: What should `-nw` do in your opinion? `man emacs` says clearly: `Tell Emacs not to create a graphical frame.  If you use this switch
when invoking Emacs from an xterm(1) window, display is done in that
window.`. It *should* make `Emacs` run in terminal.

Comment: It used to open files in a "new window" using -nw or & before. Then how else can I open it in a new window and not in the terminal?

Comment: @anita, `-nw` has caused Emacs to run in the terminal as long as I've been using it (about a decade). If you want to run Emacs graphically, _omit_ `-nw`.

Comment: @Chris omitting -nw still opens it in the terminal

Comment: @anita, then you may be running a version of Emacs that wasn't built with GUI support. OSX ships with a very old terminal-only version of Emacs. Perhaps you're getting that version instead of whatever you installed manually? Try `M-x version RET` from a running Emacs to see which version you're running, and `which emacs` from a terminal to see the full path to its binary.